# Collection of all partial functions is a set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm studying real analysis from prof. Tao's book "Analysis 1" and I'm stuck on the following exercise:

"Let $ X $ , $ Y $ be sets. Define a partial function from $ X $ to $ Y $ to be any function $ f: X' -> Y' $ whose domain $ X' $ is a subset of $ X $, and whose range $ Y' $ is a subset of $ Y $.
Show that the collection of all partial functions from $ X $ to $ Y $ is itself a set."

My attempt:
I know that if I "build" the set  {  $Y_1^{X_1} , Y_2^{X_2},... $ } ($X_i \in 2^X$, $Y_i \in 2^Y$) then the result follows immediately from the axiom of union, so my goal is to build that set.
To do so I let $ X' $ be an arbitrary element of $ 2^X $ (power set of $X$) and for every $Y' \in  2^Y$ I let $ P(Y',y):="y=Y'^{X'}"$.
From the axiom of replacement I now know that the set {$f:X'->Y'| Y' \in 2^Y$}={$Y_1^{X'}, Y_2^{X'},...$} exists.
  Now I want to allow $X'$ in the set above to vary in $2^X$ (this, together with the axiom of union should be enough to conclude the proof) but I haven't been able to do it so far (I think I should use the axiom of replacement again but I don't know how to apply it).
So, I would appreciate any hint about how to conclude this last step.

Best regards,
lorenzo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised.**

I’m assuming that you’ve already shown (or assumed) that for any sets $S$ and $T$ the set $T^S$ is well-defined.

Note that if $f:S\to T\subseteq Y$, then $f:S\to Y$ as well. Thus, we really need only

$$\bigcup\left\{Y^S:S\in 2^X\right\}\;.$$

Let $P(x,y)$ hold iff $x\in 2^X$ and $y=Y^x$, or $x\notin 2^X$ and $y=\varnothing$; clearly $P$ is functional, and $2^X$ is a set, so we can apply replacement to conclude that

$$\left\{Y^S:S\in 2^X\right\}$$

exists. Now just apply the union axiom.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; the problem with your approach is that the concept of cartesian product is defined in the text in the chapter following the one in which this problem is stated.

Comment: @lorenzo: Has the ordered pair been defined yet?

Comment: No, it is also defined in the following chapter "Cartesian products"

Comment: @lorenzo: Then how is *function* defined?

Comment: "Def.(Functions): Let X, Y be sets and let P(x,y) be a property pertaining to an object $x \in X$  and an object $y \in Y$, such that for every $x \in X $ there is exactly on $y \in Y $ for which $P(x,y)$ is true. Then we define the function $f:X->Y$ to be the object which, given any input $x \in X $, assigns an output $f(x) \in Y$, defined to be the unique object $f(x)$ for which $P(x, f(x))$ is true."

Comment: @lorenzo: Ah, I see; basically he defines a functional predicate and then uses replacement to get actual functions. Okay; I’ll give it some thought and either replace or delete this answer in a bit.

Comment: I don't understand two things:  1) you say that since $f:S \in 2^X->T \in 2^Y$ implies $f:S -> Y$ then we need only {$ Y^S: S \in 2^X$}; but to conclude that shouldn't we start from the converse implication? 2) In $P(x,y)$ why you added "or $ x \notin 2^X $ and $y= \varnothing$" to $P(x,y):="x \in 2^X $ and $y=Y^x$"; isn't this last part enough to build the desired set?

Comment: @lorenzo: (1) No: the point is no matter what subset of $Y$ is the actual range of $f$, we can view $f$ as a function from $S$ to $Y$. Thus, we need only worry about the domain. (2) Habit; I’m accustomed to making $P$ functional, i.e., satisfying $\forall x\,\exists!y\,P(x,y)$, so that replacement can be applied to it with any set as domain. It’s not necessary here.

Comment: I see; thank you for your help.

Comment: @lorenzo: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $Y$ and an element $X′$ of the power set $\mathcal{X}=\{X′:X′\subseteq X\}$ such that there is a unique power set $Y^{X′}$ for every $X′ \in X$. Then there is a set $\{Y^{X′}:X′\subseteq X\}$ such that for every $z$:
$$
z \in {Y^{X′}:X′ \subseteq X} \leftrightarrow z \text{ is the unique power set for some }X′.
$$
Now that $\{Y^{X′}:X′ \subseteq X\}$ is a set (of sets of partial functions from $X$ to $Y$) the union axiom may be applied to define the set of all partial functions from $X$ to $Y$ to be
$$ \bigcup\{Y^{X′}:X′ \subseteq X\}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Given $X$ and $Y$, form the sets $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ using the consequence of the power set axiom (Lemma 3.4.9 from the book).

Then apply the replacement axiom to $P(X)$ to get the set $\{ f(X') \colon X' \in P(X) \}$, where $f(X') = \{ Y'^{X'} \colon Y' \in P(Y) \}$. The definition of $f$ uses the set $P(Y)$, the replacement axiom applied to it and the power set axiom (as stated in Axiom 3.10 from the book) to form the function-set.

Now, apply (twice) the union axiom to the resulting set $\{ f(X') \colon X' \in P(X) \}$ and you are done.

**Remark:** in Tao's book "Analysis 1", the power set axiom (Axiom 3.10) asserts the existence of the function-set $Y^X$, despite its name. And the existence of the power set is given as a consequence (Lemma 3.4.9).