# Question about the following implication: If $f: S \to T \subseteq Y$, then $f:S\to Y$.

Tags: functions

I recently saw the following statement:

> If $f: S \to T \subseteq Y$, then $f:S\to Y$.

I wanted to make sure that I am understanding how to translate this to English. In Terence Tao's *Analysis I*, the verbatim description of function equality is:

> Two functions $f: X \to Y$ and $g: X \to Y$ **with the same domain and range** are said to be equal, $f=g$, if and only if $f(x) =g(x)$ for all $x \in X$. ... If two functions $f,g$ have different domains, **or different ranges**, we also do not consider them to be equal.

So, with the above definition in mind, how should I read the first statement?

"If $f$ is definable in this circumstance, then it is definable in this other circumstance"?

"If $f$ is definable in this circumstance, no information is lost when defining it in this other circumstance?"

Any suggestions?

The reason this is important is because of how the statement "If $f: S \to T \subseteq Y$, then $f:S\to Y$" was used in a proof. Specifically, the $f$ in the antecedent was replaced by the $f$ in the consequent. That to me seems to suggest equivalence...but they are not *really* equivalent, are they?

Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f : S \to T$ gives you the function $i \circ f : S \to Y$, where $i : T \to Y$ denote the inclusion function $i(t) = t$. The functions $f$ and $i \circ f$ are not the same, but sometimes *notation is abused* by writing $f : S \to Y$ instead of $i \circ f$. It depends on the proof whether this is harmless or not.

**Edited:**

The question is based on [Collection of all partial functions is a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244040) . In my opinion the existing answers are not sufficient to prove Tao's claim.

Let us assume as in the accepted answer that it has been shown that for any two sets $S$ and $T$ the collection $T^S$ of  all functions $S \to T$ is a *set*.

Then we can form the union
$$\bigcup_{(X',Y') \in P(X) \times P(Y)} (Y')^{X'}$$
which is again a set. This set consists of all partial functions from $X$ to $Y$. Note that the sets $(Y')^{X'}$ are pairwise disjoint.

However, if we identify partial functions $f : X' \to Y' \subset Y$ with functions $f : X' \to Y$, then certainly
$$\bigcup_{X' \in P(X)} Y^{X'} \subsetneqq \bigcup_{(X',Y') \in P(X) \times P(Y)} (Y')^{X'} .$$

**Edited:**

See Asaf Karagila's answer to [Set of all partial functions exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212305) for a proof not using the product $P(X) \times P(Y)$. We only need the power set axiom, Lemma 3.4.8 and twice the axiom of union.

But let me emphasize again that $Y^{X'}$ is not the same as $\bigcup_{Y' \in  P(Y)} (Y')^{X'}$.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The proof can be found in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244040/collection-of-all-partial-functions-is-a-set

Comment: The accepted answer is where the implication is used.

Comment: He basically is replacing a subset of the codomain with simply the entire codomain in order to format the syntax so that it is more amenable to the specific style of an axiom.

Comment: Okay, I shall edit my answer.

Comment: That's sort of how I derived it as well; however, as the "question-asker" pointed out in that link (it's in one of the comments), Tao actually has not yet introduced the concept of a cartesian product. This is why, I believe, @BrianM.Scott structured his answer in this particular fashion. As a side note, I'm not sure that your version demonstrates that $(Y')^{X'}$ is actually a set. In other words, I dont think you have demonstrated that the collection of all sets of partial functions from a specific sub-domain to a specific sub-codomain is a set. I think you need to do this before the union.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott accomplishes this by utilizing the axiom of replacement in his bracketed statement: $\{Y^S:S\in 2^X\}$

Comment: In fact my proof in the "Edit" requires three ingredients: (1) For any two sets $S$ and $T$ the collection $T^S$ of all functions $S \to T$ is a set. (2) Defining the product of two sets and showing that it is again a set. (3) The axiom of union. However, this is not what you asked in your question. What we can definitely say is that $\bigcup\left\{Y^S:S\in 2^X\right\}$ is not the same as the collection of all partial functions$ f : X′ \to Y′ \subset Y$.

Comment: By the way, how does Tao define the concept of a function $f : S  \to T$? The standard definition known to me is to regarad it as a suitable subset of $S \times T$. This would require the previous introduction of products.

Comment: "Def.(Functions): Let $X, Y$ be sets and let $P(x,y)$ be a property pertaining to an object $x \in X$ and an object $y \in Y$, such that for every $x \in X$ there is exactly on $y \in Y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is true. Then we define the function $f:X \to Y$ to be the object which, given any input $x \in X$, assigns an output $f(x) \in Y$, defined to be the unique object $f(x)$ for which $P(x,f(x))$ is true."

Comment: I had a look into Tao's book and realized that his approach to set theory is somewhat unconventional. For example, the "Power set axiom" states that $T^S$ is a set and what I would understand as the *power set axiom* occurs as Lemma 3.4.8.